# Краш программы с перегрузкой оператора вывода

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Компилятор не выдаёт ошибок, но если выполнить следующий код появляется окно с сообщением: "Программа не работает".

```
int main()
{
    STRING string;
    cin>>string;
    cout<<1<<endl;
}
```

Собственно класс STRING:

```
class STRING
{
    private:
        TCHAR* string;
    public:
        STRING(){};
        STRING(TCHAR* concat)
        {
            delete[] string;
            string = new TCHAR[_tcslen(concat)];
            _tcscpy(string, concat);
        };
        friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const STRING& concat)
        {
            _tprintf(concat.string);
            return out;
        };
        friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, const STRING& object)
        {
            delete[] object.string;
            _tscanf(L"%s", object.string);
            return in;
        };
};
```

Comment: А что, по-вашему, делает функция `_tscanf`? (При ответе можно подсматривать в документацию.)

Comment: @Abyx так нет ещё вопроса о том, как пользоваться отладчиком ... :-D

Comment: @VlaD функция _tscanf считывает отформатированные данные из стандартного входного потока (msdn).

Comment: @ИльяКолдунов: Так, хорошо, а куда она их девает после прочтения?

Comment: @VlaD если вы намекаете на оператор delete[], то его я уже давно убрал, спасибо)

Comment: @ИльяКолдунов: Хорошо, но это не всё. Сколько памяти нужно для введённой строки? А сколько выделено у вас?

Answer (score 3):

Пишу замечания как комментарии

```
class STRING
{
    private:
        TCHAR* string;
    public:
        STRING(){};
        // string не инициализирован!!

        STRING(TCHAR* concat)
        {
            delete[] string;
            // Что вы здесь удаляете? string пока что содержит мусор!

            string = new TCHAR[_tcslen(concat)];
            // О завершающем нулевом символе вы забыли?

            _tcscpy(string, concat);
        };

        // Где в этой функции используется out?
        friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const STRING& concat)
        {
            _tprintf(concat.string);
            // Что будем делать, если в string будет символ %??

            return out;
        };
        // Где в этой функции используется in?
        friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, const STRING& object)
        {
            delete[] object.string;
            // Итак, вы удалили выделенную память
            _tscanf(L"%s", object.string);
            // и читаете в нее??!! Все, object.string 
            // после предыдущего удаления недоступен!
            // И, кстати, даже если бы был доступен -
            // сколько в него можно прочесть символов?
            // А если будет введено больше, чем выделено места?

            return in;
        };
};
```

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, как можно в таком случае выделить память для строки прямо в перегрузке ввода или считать безразмерную строку. Пробовал пользоваться out'ом, но он выводит не строку, а номер первого символа в таблице ASCII - _tprintf приятнее цикла for.

Comment: Крайне рекомендую использовать готовый класс - `string` и соответствующие функции для ввода: нужный буфер будет выделен без вашего участия.

Comment: но ведь класс string не прининимается функциями winapi, а этот класс создаётся именно для него.

Comment: Внутренне-то кто вам мешает его использовать? А потом в API передадите указатель, получаемый с помощью `.c_str()`. Иначе нужно читать по кускам и при необходимости увеличивать размер буфера, в который читаете.