# Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00EF7738

Tags: c++

объясните, в чём ошибка и как исправить [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
char letters[30];
char a;
string M;
cin >> M;
int x, w;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 29; i++) {
    letters[i] = (char)M[i];
}

for (x = 0; x < 28; x++) {
    for (w = x + 1; x < 29; w++) {
        if (letters[w] < letters[x]) {
            a = letters[w];
            letters[w] = letters[x];
            letters[x] = a;
        }
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < 29; i++) { cout << letters[i] << " "; }

system("pause");
return(0);
}
```

Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00EF7738 в ConsoleApplication3.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00701000., произошло

Comment: `(char)M[i]` зачем?

Comment: А вы умеете пользоваться отладчиком?

Comment: Без отладчика нет смысла писать что-то сложнее Hello World. Овладевайте им, выше верно говорят!

Comment: (char)M[i] чтобы по символам разделить

Comment: @VladD вот точно вопрос [надо писать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/718135/%d0%9a%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%88-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0#comment1080608_718135) по отладке в плюсах :)

Comment: @alexolut: Даааа! Только надо с плюсовой спецификой, например, отладка с отключёнными оптимизациями, чтобы не словить UB.

Answer (score 4):

```
for (w = x + 1; x < 29; w++) {
```

Так как значение `x` внутри этого цикла никак не меняется, это - бесконечный цикл, т.е. неопределенное поведение. Программа по-видимому падает когда значение `w` вылетает за пределы допустимых индексов для массива `letters[]`.

Что вы хотели сказать этим странным циклом?

Comment: первый цикл выбирает букву, второй - сравнивает сотавшиеся после этой буквы с выбранное и если прокнет условие то меняет их метами

Comment: @WoWkiller 11: Еще раз: условие внутреннего цикла - `x < 29` - всегда заведомо истинно. То есть цикл выполняется бесконечно. Что вы хотели сказать таким условием? Зачем оно такое?